# Structured data in confluence

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api, atlassian-plugin-sdk

is there a way to use structured data for confluence pages or even decouple the data from the view and access only the data by an API?
Are there any solutions without using any plugins?

Thank you and kind regards